# Application UI with Spark Stand Alone Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to access the Application Detail UI of a job submitted to Spark Stand Alone cluster (v 1.4). I submitted using the following command:

```
./spark-submit --master spark://MASTER:7077 --deploy-mode cluster ....
```

Seems like the link to "Application Detail UI" (port:4040) is broken. Everything works if I submit locally (remove `--deploy-mode cluster`).

Is there a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a URL for the application UI printed in the log file. Search for the words "started SparkUI at" and you should find it.

Comment: I looked inside /root/spark/logs folder of all the workers and master. Could not find any such line.

Comment: It would be logged where you are running spark_submit.sh from. Maybe your log4j configuration is broken. The message is logged at level "INFO". If you are not seeing INFO level messages check the log4j.properties in the conf directory.